# How can I change the value of a fields inside a collection that is part of an object

Tags: c#, collections

I have the following classes:

```
public class Question {
    public Question() { this.Answers = new List<Answer>(); }
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}

public class Answer {
    public int AnswerId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following that someone suggested as a way to check the strings and remove an ending. I put this into a method and it looks like this now:

```
    public static string cleanQuestion(string text)
    {
        if (text == null) { return null; }
        else {
            return (Regex.Replace(text, "<p>&nbsp;</p>$", ""));
        }
    }
```

I know how to call this method on the Text field for the question. But how could I call the method on
each of the Answer Text fields?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about changing the property to a field-backed property:

```
public class Answer {
    private string _text;

    public int AnswerId { get; set; }
    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set { _text = Class.cleanQuestion(value); }
    }
}
```

where `Class` is the class the `static` method is on.

Now, every time an answer gets `Text`, it will be cleaned.

On the other hand. If you **want** the `Text` to contain the un-cleansed value, except for in certain cases, you could build a `get` property on the `Answer` class:

```
public string CleanText
{
    get { return Class.cleanQuestion(this.Text); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following :

```
    Question q = new Question();

    foreach (Answer ans in q.Answers) {
        string cleanedText = cleanQuestion(ans.Text);
    }
```

This will itterate over each of the Answers in the Collection within your Question Object, and call the method with the parameter of the answer text.

Answer (score 0):

I would think just go through each `Question`:

```
foreach(Anser answer in question.Answers)
  answer.Text = cleanQuestion(answer.Text);
```

However, I would also say that maybe you should add `cleanQuestion()` to the `Question` class as a `method`. This way, you could just call `CleanQuestions()`, and it would go through each answer on it's own.

Comment: I was thinking of this way but then thought I would only be changing a local copy of answer? Does this really change the actual value in the question object ?

Comment: It will change the value of the `Text` in the `Question`.  Try it and see!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the original answers:

Question class:

```
public List<Answer> CleanAnswers {
    get {
        return Answers.Select(a => a.CleanText()).ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer class:

```
public string CleanText()
{
    if (this.Text == null) { return null; }
    else {
        return (Regex.Replace(this.Text, "<p>&nbsp;</p>$", ""));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also go for Extension method approach would be more handy.

```
public class Question
{
    public Question() { this.Answers = new List<Answer>(); }
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}

public static class TextExtension
{
    public static string CleanQuestion(this Question @this)
    {
        if (@this.Text == null) { return null; }
        else
        {
            return (Regex.Replace(@this.Text, "<p>&nbsp;</p>$", ""));
        }
    } 
}


    // Usage:
    Question q1= new Question();
    q1.CleanQuestion();
```